# SOLR search not including data within JSON Field

Tags: search, solr, lucene, solrconfig

I have a bunch of documents included in my SOLR index. These documents contain a field that contains JSON data.

When I perform a query with a keyword I want that JSON field to be also searched. Right now it is not working.

**QUERY:**

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "q":"keyword_to_search",
      "defType":"edismax",
      "qf":"title^300",
      "fl":"field_name:[json]",
      "wt":"json",
      "_":"1551735180672"
    }
  },
  "response":{
    "numFound":0,
    "start":0,
    "docs":[]
  }
}
```

There is actual documents that contains a JSON field with the data 'keyword_to_search'.

```
"field_name":"{\"field_key\": \"keyword_to_search\"}",
```

The field seems to be searchable as I can return the document when querying:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "q":"{!term f=field_name}keyword_to_search",
      "_":"1551735532524"
    }
  },
  "response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":[
    {
    ...
    "field_name":"{\"field_key\": \"keyword_to_search\"}",
    }
  ]}
}
```

How can modify my query to include this?

**JSON Structure:**

```
{
  ...
  "field_name": "field_value",
  "columns": [
    ...
    {
        "nested_key": "nested_value_1"
    },
    {
        "nested_key": "nested_value_1"
    },
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`qf=title^300` tells Solr which fields it should search and the weight given to each field.

`qf=title^300 json` would search both the `title` field and the `json` field, and give a hit in `title` a 300x increase in score compared to a hit it `json`.

Comment: Thanks, this makes the query very slow due to the size of the JSON field. Should I index this as separate documents? If so how do I relate these to the parent, as thats what I want to be returned not the new json docs.

Comment: If there's a specific field in the JSON you want to search, index it as a separate field. How much content are we talking about here? Extracting it as a separate document won't reduce the amount of tokens to be searched, so it'll depend on the definition of `field_name` as well.

Comment: Its a large JSON object, over 20k characters. I added the structure of the JSON field to the original post. I need to search 3/4 items contained within the array objects.

Comment: I am accepting this answer as it did work. thank you.